# Redim Preserve gives 'subscript out of range'

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, subroutine, preserve

I want to `Redim Preserve` an array I keep getting the error 'subscript out of range'. I am aware of the fact that only the size of the last dimension can be changed. That is exactly what I am doing. What is going wrong over here? The type of the array is `Variant`.

```
BmMatrix = Sheets("BENCH").Range("a60", ActiveSheet.Range("a60").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
'totaal gewicht per subdeel in array wegschrijven
Dim aBmMatrix()
aBmMatrix = BmMatrix
rij = UBound(BmMatrix, 1)
kol = UBound(BmMatrix, 2) + 1
ReDim Preserve aBmMatrix(rij, kol)
TotGewKol = UBound(aBmMatrix, 2)
For i = 2 To UBound(BmMatrix, 1)
    g = 0 'g wordt totaal gewicht van land bv
    If BmMatrix(i, bm_kolom) <> "x" Then
        For j = 2 To UBound(bmexnul, 1)
            If bmexnul(j, weightkolom) = BmMatrix(i, bm_kolom) Then g = g + bmexnul(j, 10)
        Next j
    End If
    aBmMatrix(i, TotGewKol) = g
    aBmMatrix(1, TotGewKol) = "Totaal gewicht" 'titel kolom
Next i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you assign `aBmMatrix` array using the `Value` property of a range, the returned array has lower bounds of `1` for each dimension.

When you later redim it without providing lower bounds explicitly, the redim tries to assign each dimension the default lower bound, which is `0`.

You need to explicitly provide the lower bounds:

```
ReDim Preserve aBmMatrix(lbound(aBmMatrix,1) to rij, lbound(aBmMatrix,2) to kol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use preserve when you change only the last dimension of an array.