# How to add to an array from within a function in VBScript?

Tags: multidimensional-array, vbscript, preserve

I'm having trouble writing a function that will output an array of records. What I am attempting to do is call a **function** that gets all the records in a table and will create a **multi-dimensional array** that I can use in the page that calls the function.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 function get_admins 
    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.cursorType = 3
    getsql = "select * from users order by name asc"
    rs.Open getsql, conn
    total = rs.RecordCount
    ra = array
    c = 0
    if total < 1 then 
        o = "There are no admins yet."
    else
        do until rs.EOF
        id = rs.Fields("id").value
        username = rs.Fields("username").value
        adminname = rs.Fields("name").value
        email = rs.Fields("email").value

        Redim Preserve ra(c,4) '<-- This is the line the error doesn't like
    ra(c,0) = id
    ra(c,1) = username
    ra(c,2) = adminname
    ra(c,3) = email
    c = c + 1

        rs.MoveNext
        loop

       end if
      rs.close
      get_admins = ra
    end function
```

**This is the error I get:**

> Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a0009'
>
> Subscript out of range

Function call on the page looks like this:

```
<pre><%
        dim seeme 
    set seeme = get_admins
%></pre>
```

*Here are some similar questions I found:*

[Classic ASP 3.0 Create Array from a Recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558998/classic-asp-3-0-create-array-from-a-recordset) - Helped a lot, but not quite there.

[Redim Preserve gives 'subscript out of range'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055734/redim-preserve-gives-subscript-out-of-range) - This one just straight confused me.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - thanks. I guess that would be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReDim Preserve` can only change the size of the last dimension in multidimensional arrays, so it's not really useful in your situation. What you can use is an array of arrays, though:

```
ReDim ra(-1)  'initialize record array as empty array
...
Else
  Do Until rs.EOF
    ReDim va(3)  'initialize value array (clear values)
    va(0) = rs.Fields("id").value
    va(1) = rs.Fields("username").value
    va(2) = rs.Fields("name").value
    va(3) = rs.Fields("email").value

    Redim Preserve ra(UBound(ra)+1) 'grow record array
    ra(UBound(ra)) = va             'put value array into record array

    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
End If
```

That will allow you to access the elements of the nested arrays like this:

```
WScript.Echo ra(3)(1)
```

The above will print the 2<sup>nd</sup> value (index 1) from the 4<sup>th</sup> nested array (index 3).

As for returning the array, you cannot use the `Set` keyword in the assignment:

```
set seeme = get_admins   '<-- will fail!
```

That's because that keyword is reserved for object assignments and arrays aren't objects. Change that line to this:

```
seeme = get_admins
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much!! I was at wit's end. That solved my problem.

Comment: @Ansgar - That's a (hard) working solution, but please take back your claim that you can't ReDim Preserve multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Granted, you can resize the last dimension. I'm not aware of a way to resize the other dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rolling your own, look at the [.GetRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

To put some code behind my claim:

```
  Dim oTCN  : Set oTCN = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
  Dim sTDir : sTDir    = "M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\txt"  ' <-- ohne \ am Ende!
  Dim sCS   : sCS      = Join( Array( _
                                "Provider=MSDASQL" _
                              , "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}" _
                              , "DBQ=" & sTDir _
                         ), ";" )
  oTCN.Open sCS
  Dim oRS
  Set oRS = oTCN.Execute("SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [gendata.txt]")
  Dim nUB : nUB = oRS.Fields.Count - 1
  ReDim aRow(nUB) ' array for one row
  ReDim aRows(nUB, -1) ' 2nd dim growable array for all rows
  Dim f
  For f = 0 To UBound(aRow)
      aRow(f) = oRS.Fields(f).Name
  Next
  WScript.Echo Join(aRow, ",")
  Do Until oRS.EOF
     ReDim Preserve aRows(nUB, UBound(aRows, 2) + 1)
     For f = 0 To UBound(aRow)
         aRow(f) = oRS.Fields(f).Value
         aRows(f, UBound(aRows, 2)) = oRS.Fields(f).Value
     Next
     WScript.Echo Join(aRow, ",")
     oRS.MoveNext
  Loop
  oRS.MoveFirst
  Dim aMagic : aMagic = oRS.GetRows() ' this is all you need!
  Dim r, c
  For r = 0 To UBound(aMagic, 2)
      For c = 0 To UBound(aMagic, 1)
          WScript.Echo r, c, aMagic(c, r), aRows(c, r)
      Next
      WScript.Echo
  Next

  oTCN.Close
```

output:

```
=============================================================
iID,sFrsName,sLstName,sSex,dtBirth
1,Yqiqpbcmunrzvi,Pmyqcxfoffrfnwbd,U,8/7/2008
2,Viyvfshpxu,Xjtfbjuiiwojhyjwkefcu,U,7/27/2008
3,Hoocyseiiiawrt,Mrpuhzuhysslzhwhnpp,F,8/7/2008
0 0 1 1
0 1 Yqiqpbcmunrzvi Yqiqpbcmunrzvi
0 2 Pmyqcxfoffrfnwbd Pmyqcxfoffrfnwbd
0 3 U U
0 4 07.08.2008 07.08.2008

1 0 2 2
1 1 Viyvfshpxu Viyvfshpxu
1 2 Xjtfbjuiiwojhyjwkefcu Xjtfbjuiiwojhyjwkefcu
1 3 U U
1 4 27.07.2008 27.07.2008

2 0 3 3
2 1 Hoocyseiiiawrt Hoocyseiiiawrt
2 2 Mrpuhzuhysslzhwhnpp Mrpuhzuhysslzhwhnpp
2 3 F F
2 4 07.08.2008 07.08.2008

=============================================================
```

So - contrary to Ansgar's "You can't use ReDim Preserve on multidimensional arrays" - you can grow the last dimension of an multidimensional array. That means you have to grow the rows and layout your array in a col/row instead of the more 'natural' row/col structure.

aRows shows how you roll your own .GetRows correctly. Of course the sane strategy is to **use**, as in

```
Dim aMagic : aMagic = oRS.GetRows() ' this is all you need!
```